# Is it possible to generate only Jitsi Meet link programatically (without any jitsi UI)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I had tried Jitsi IFrame API in my react application but it give its own UI. I just want only an url of jitsi meet and send it to the email.

Tried this link too:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jitsi-demo-qjoei?module=/src/VideoConference.jsx&file=/src/VideoConference.jsx:0-1129

Comment: type in the link with random name at the end. for e.g `https://meet.jit.si/thisistherandomchannel`.

Comment: @Sid you save my whole week. This is what I wanted. Thank you so much !!!